# Adaptive Histogram Equalization in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to implement adaptive histogram equalization in python. I take an image and split it into smaller regions and then apply the traditional histogram equalization to it. I then combine the smaller images into one and obtain a final resultant image. The final image appears to be very blocky in nature and has different contrast levels for each individual region. Is there a way I could maintain a uniform contrast for each individual image so that it looks like a single image instead of smaller images stitched together.

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imsave
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc
import scipy

import image_slicer
from image_slicer import join
from PIL import Image

img = 'watch.png'
num_tiles = 25
tiles = image_slicer.slice(img, num_tiles)


for tile in tiles:
    img = scipy.misc.imread(tile.filename)
    hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    cdf_normalized = cdf *hist.max()/ cdf.max()  
    plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'g')
    plt.hist(img.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'g')
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
    cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
    cdf_o = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
    cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_o,0).astype('uint8')
    img3 = cdf[img]
    cv2.imwrite(tile.filename,img3)
    tile.image = Image.open(tile.filename

image = join(tiles)
image.save('watch-join.png')
```

Comment: Are you sure this algorithmic approach is what you want? The result you are seeing is what's expected. Of course there is not much smoothness. As i'm not familiar with adaptive hist-eq, i looked up wikipedia and the algorithm there is very different (sliding-window based; no non-overlapping blocks like in your case) and obviously results in something much more smooth. You can also check out [skimage's approach/implementation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist).

Comment: the output is what is to be expected given your approach to the problem... you treat each block differently due to their different histograms. did you read any papers or any open source code on that problem? there is no reason to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: @sascha I have posted a different code to achieve AHE. Would it be possible for you to review it and suggest any changes to improve it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed the actual algorithm and came up with the following implementation. I am sure there is a better way to do this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('watch.png',0)
print img
img_size=img.shape
print img_size

img_mod = np.zeros((600, 800))

for i in range(0,img_size[0]-30):
    for j in range(0,img_size[1]-30):
        kernel = img[i:i+30,j:j+30]
        for k in range(0,30):
            for l in range(0,30):
                element = kernel[k,l]
                rank = 0
                for m in range(0,30):
                    for n in range(0,30):
                        if(kernel[k,l]>kernel[m,n]):
                            rank = rank + 1
                img_mod[i,j] = ((rank * 255 )/900)

im = np.array(img_mod, dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('target.png',im)
```